# Make quantile selection into a slider

Tags: r, shiny, slider

I wonder if it is possible to make this part `quantile(value, probs = c(0, .4, .8))` in my `survfit` function below into a slider that goes from 0-1. The slider has to control the first and the last part of the quantile (the 0.4 and 0.8 part in my example), so it may have to be two separate sliders.

I tried this, but got the error that `input not found`

```
  dashboardBody(
    sliderInput("obs1", "LowQuantile",
                min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.1
    ),
    sliderInput("obs2", "HighQuantile",
                min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.1
    )


fitSurv <-   survfit(Surv(TimeDiff, Status) ~ cut(value,
                                                      quantile(value, probs = c(0, input$obs1,input$obs2)),
                                                      include.lowest=TRUE),
                         data = data_selected())
```

Here is my app:

```
library(dplyr) 
require(survminer)
library(tidyverse)
require(reshape2)
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
require(survival)
```

example data:

```
 df.miRNA.cpm <-     structure(list(`86` = c(5.57979757386892, 17.0240095264258, 4.28380151026145, 
13.0457611762755, 12.5531123449841), `175` = c(5.21619202802748, 
15.2849097474841, 2.46719979911461, 10.879496005461, 9.66416497290915
), `217` = c(5.42796072966512, 17.1413407297933, 5.15230233060323, 
12.2646127361351, 12.1031024927547), `394` = c(-1.1390337316217, 
15.1021660424984, 4.63168157763046, 11.1299079134792, 9.55572588729967
), `444` = c(5.06134249676025, 14.5442494311861, -0.399445049232868, 
7.45775961504073, 9.92629675808998)), row.names = c("hsa_let_7a_3p", 
"hsa_let_7a_5p", "hsa_let_7b_3p", "hsa_let_7b_5p", "hsa_let_7c_5p"
), class = "data.frame")

df.miRNA.cpm$miRNA <- rownames(df.miRNA.cpm)


  ss.survival.shiny.miRNA.miRNA <-   structure(list(ID = c("86", "175", "217", "394", "444"), TimeDiff = c(71.0416666666667, 
601.958333333333, 1130, 1393, 117.041666666667), Status = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Joint the two example data frames:

```
 data_prep.miRNA <- df.miRNA.cpm %>% 
tidyr::pivot_longer(-miRNA, names_to = "ID") %>% 
left_join(ss.survival.shiny.miRNA.miRNA)
```

Shiny:

```
ui.miRNA <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("MicroRNA", "miRNA", choices = unique(data_prep.miRNA$miRNA)),

  plotOutput("myplot"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_selected <- reactive({
    filter(data_prep.miRNA, miRNA %in% input$MicroRNA)
  })
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
      fitSurv <-   survfit(Surv(TimeDiff, Status) ~ cut(value, quantile(value, probs = c(0, .4, .8)), include.lowest=TRUE),data = data_selected())

    ggsurvplot(fitSurv,data_selected ())
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui.miRNA, server)
```

Comment: If you just want to control 2 values, you can use `sliderInput` as a range slider if you provide the `value` argument with 2 values (see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.4.0/sliderInput.html))

Comment: I have tried, but got an error with the input. Please see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem here is a scoping issue in one of the functions called by `ggsurvfit`. Nested deeply in the function call, `stats::get_all_vars` is called. This function somehow leads to a scoping problem and it doesn't find the variables used for the lower/upper quantile because they are not contained in the dataframe that is provided as the input for the `data` argument. However, `stats::get_all_vars` accepts an environment instead of a dataframe. Therefore, my hack is to not pass a dataframe, but an environment in the `data` argument of `ggsurvfit`. The environment then contains all needed variables from the dataframe used for model building as well as the variables for the quantiles. I feel that this is not an optimal solution and are happy for better ones.

Also, I only use one slider to select the values for the quantiles:

```
library(dplyr) 
require(survminer)
library(tidyverse)
require(reshape2)
library(shiny)
library(tidyr)
require(survival)

df.miRNA.cpm <-     structure(list(`86` = c(5.57979757386892, 17.0240095264258, 4.28380151026145, 
                                            13.0457611762755, 12.5531123449841), `175` = c(5.21619202802748, 
                                                                                           15.2849097474841, 2.46719979911461, 10.879496005461, 9.66416497290915
                                            ), `217` = c(5.42796072966512, 17.1413407297933, 5.15230233060323, 
                                                         12.2646127361351, 12.1031024927547), `394` = c(-1.1390337316217, 
                                                                                                        15.1021660424984, 4.63168157763046, 11.1299079134792, 9.55572588729967
                                                         ), `444` = c(5.06134249676025, 14.5442494311861, -0.399445049232868, 
                                                                      7.45775961504073, 9.92629675808998)), row.names = c("hsa_let_7a_3p", 
                                                                                                                          "hsa_let_7a_5p", "hsa_let_7b_3p", "hsa_let_7b_5p", "hsa_let_7c_5p"
                                                                      ), class = "data.frame")

df.miRNA.cpm$miRNA <- rownames(df.miRNA.cpm)


ss.survival.shiny.miRNA.miRNA <-   structure(list(ID = c("86", "175", "217", "394", "444"), TimeDiff = c(71.0416666666667, 
                                                                                                         601.958333333333, 1130, 1393, 117.041666666667), Status = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                     1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
data_prep.miRNA <- df.miRNA.cpm %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-miRNA, names_to = "ID") %>% 
  left_join(ss.survival.shiny.miRNA.miRNA)

ui.miRNA <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("MicroRNA", "miRNA", choices = unique(data_prep.miRNA$miRNA)),
  sliderInput("obs", "Quantiles",
              min = 0, max = 1, value = c(0.4, 0.8)
  ),
  
  plotOutput("myplot"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_selected <- reactive({
    filter(data_prep.miRNA, miRNA %in% input$MicroRNA)
  })
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    lower_value <- input$obs[1]
    upper_value <- input$obs[2]
    fitSurv <-   survfit(Surv(TimeDiff, Status) ~ cut(value, quantile(value, probs = c(0, lower_value, upper_value)), include.lowest=TRUE),data = data_selected())
    
    new_env <- environment()
    new_env$value <- data_selected()$value
    new_env$TimeDiff <- data_selected()$TimeDiff
    new_env$Status <- data_selected()$Status
    new_env$lower_value <- lower_value
    new_env$upper_value <- upper_value
    ggsurvplot(fitSurv, new_env)
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui.miRNA, server)
```